# Install os x SL on MBP faileure

Tags: windows-10, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, osx-el-capitan, dmg-image

I have MacBook Pro mid-09, it had el capitan os before I removed it

I wanted to work completely on win10, and completely **formatted all the HDD** with the recovery partition included

But realised later I need os x badly, and i dont have internet recovery option
So **I downloaded snow leopard.dmg and made a usb bootable drive** using transmac on windows

**It loaded but it says it can't be installed on this computer** it offers using time machine (i dont have backup!) Or restart

What can I do now ?

I can't go to apple store to repair it i'm much far away from one !

[image: http://pictub.club/image/R8rMk]

Comment: If it can boot off of the flash drive, can you access Disk Utility?

Comment: For future reference, deleting OS X from a Mac entirely is a really bad plan because it makes firmware updates difficult or impossible. If you're never ever going to use it, leave OS X installed on the smallest possible partition.

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac and a FireWire cable?

Comment: It doesn't give me access to disk utility or any tool,only that message with restart and use time machine backup buttons ,unfortunately no nearby Macs around me

Comment: I think you need to revisit how you made the bootable flash drive then. If memory serves it should get you a grey screen with white window in the middle where you can access recovery tools... Could you add an image of what you're getting now?

Comment: http://pictub.club/image/R8rMk

Comment: I assume cmd-r on startup doesn't work, right? Goes to a blank screen?

Comment: Your flash drive, if it's made right, shouldn't just try to install OS X immediately. If you're successfully booting from it, you should have the option of using disk utility instead of immediately starting the installation

Comment: Maybe because i am using a usb hard drive instead of flash? Or maybe beacause i made it through win?